# Django. URL, media настройки для отображения img

Tags: python, django

`pyhon 3`, `django 1.8`, `pillow` установлены. Есть модель с `ImageField`. Нужно отобразить на странице картинку из модели. Мне кажется, я напутал в сеттингсах (вообще я новичок и с картинками первый раз работаю).

```
tovar_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads', default='/img/tovar.jpg')
```

Во вьюхе подгружаю все объекты из модели и передаю как:

```
{{ tovar.tovar_img }}
```

Вместо картинок получаю путь: при дефолте `/static/tovar.jpg` и при заданной `./tovar1.jpg`

Помогите сформировать сеттингс пути верно, чтобы подгружать и загружать картинки в одну папку, ну и, соответственно, чтобы они отображались.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'uploads')
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [ ('static', 'C:/Python34/mynewage/static'), ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` - это часть пути к картинкам (http://site.com/MEDIA_URL/photo.jpg) на Вашем сайте (не имеет отношения к структуре данных на диске, т.е. к папкам). Задавая MEDIA_URL не забудьте добавить `'django.template.context_processors.media'` к контекстным процессорам (context_processors)

2) `{{ MEDIA_ROOT }}` - это папка на диске, в которую будут сохраняться все картинки, которые загрузит пользователь

3) `{{ STATIC_URL }}` - в данном контексте он неважен

4) `tovar_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads', default='/img/tovar.jpg')` - при таких настройках фотографии будут сохраняться в папку 'uploads' в папке MEDIA_ROOT (MEDIA_ROOT/uploads/filename.jpg - например). Также в папку MEDIA_ROOT/img/tovar.jpg - Вам нужно положить этот самый дефолтный файл

5) Вывод осуществляется в template через тег img (например): `<img src="{{ tovar.tovar_img.url }}" alt="товар">`

6) Если Вы разрабатываете сайт (не в продакшене - для этого есть nginx/apache), то добавьте в urls.py (чтобы dev-сервер мог раздавать media-файлы)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
# ...
urlpatterns = [
    # ... 
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

6) для контентных картинок, особенно для интернет-магазина, очень рекомендую [solr.thumbnail](https://github.com/mariocesar/sorl-thumbnail) - позволяет отдавать картинки определенного размера (с сохранением соотношения сторон, что важно, так как контент-менеджер может залить кривую картинку, которая в противном случае вылезет из границ/будет криво масштабирована)

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример как это делаю я:

```
<div class="thumb" style="background-image: url({{ video.thumbnail.url }});"></div>
```

То есть у объекта `video` есть `ImageField` `thumbnail`. Чтобы получить ссылку нужно всего лишь у объекта изображения запросить атрибут `url`.